# Use the Calender of a Microsoft Teams Office 365 Group

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, outlook-web-app

When I create Office 365 groups outside teams, I get an Outlook mailbox and a shared calendar. But when I create a team, I don't see the group in my Outlook - so far so clear. But is it possible to use a shared calendar for the Office 365 (Teams) group?

Since every O365 group has its own e-mail address, I simply tried to open a new calendar in my Outlook. So I entered the e-mail address of the O365 group and inserted the calendar. It looked like I could use the calendar. But when I closed and reopened the Outlook app, the added calendar was gone. When I tried to add it again, I got the message that I don't have the necessary rights to do so. Something is very strange here... So is there an ootb way to use a shared O365 group calendar?

As a member of a team I can see the scheduled meetings in my own calendar. But we also want to plan other things together. That is where this question comes from.

Many thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: We are checking this.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Had to run PowerShell script to make it visible (if using MFA, you'll need to use an app password)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
set-UnifiedGroup -identity "InventoryTeam" -HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled:$false
```